# Symfony - Group sequence defined part in entity and in form type

Tags: symfony, validation, entity

It looks like there's something I can't understand. It will be a long post, so I'll try to be concise.

I try to use GroupSequence in Symfony 4.2, but I'm facing an issue. Goal I want to achieve is adding an unmapped field and define GroupSequence in FormType (because I want to use another FormType on this entity without this unmapped field). I want this unmapped field "verified" to be check before other constraints on the form.

Problem is I can't manage to enable part of the validation using Group Sequence in this particular case.

Sample code : https://github.com/sarramegnag/groupsequence-issue

Here's my entity code :

```
<?php // src/Entity/Product.php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * 
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * 
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * 
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $price;

    ...
```

And my form type code :

```
<?php // src/Form/ProductType.php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Product;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\GroupSequence;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('price')
            ->add('verified', CheckboxType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(['groups' => ['Strict']]),
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Product::class,
            'validation_groups' => new GroupSequence(['Strict', 'Product']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

It works if I set attribute and the assertion in the entity and map it as a normal field.

```
// src/Entity/Product.php

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"Strict"})
 */
private $verified = false;

...

public function isVerified(): ?bool
{
    return $this->verified;
}

public function setVerified(bool $verified): self
{
    $this->verified = $verified;

    return $this;
}

// src/Form/ProductType.php

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('description')
        ->add('price')
        ->add('verified', CheckboxType::class)
    ;
}
```

In fact, it works as soon I set a group on an assertion in the entity.

Thank you for your time and let me know if I'm not being very clear.

Guillaume

Comment: looks like its a GroupSequence bug (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/9939). i think it does work if you use annotations only